# AG Grid - SSRM Pivot for SELECT f, count(f) FROM t GROUP BY f

Tags: ag-grid

I'm developing a server-side row model using AG Grid.  I'd like to configure the grid in pivot mode to produce a query that is the equivalent of `SELECT email_id, count(email_id) FROM t GROUP BY email_id`.  I believe this is the proper way to configure the grid using the Columns sidebar accessory:

[image]

The request object that AG Grid generates has the same data in the `valueCols` field as the `rowGroupCols` field.  The `id` and `field` values are identical.  How should the server return the results to differentiate between the `email_id` column and the `count(email_id)` column?  Ideally, the `id`s or 'field`s would to differentiate between the two results.

I have tried changing the `id` and `field` values in the grid configuration by responding to grid change events but this feels like a hack and fails due to timing issues between the onChange events and the `getRows` request.